# Saving data to first model and using the generated key to save data to other model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model named **Product** that belongs to two model namely **User** and **Address**.

```
 class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :address
    validates :title, :description, :user_id, :address_id, presence: true
    validates :product_type, numericality:{:greater_than => 0, :less_than_or_equal_to => 2}, presence: true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end
```

Now the problem is that a user will enter the address at the time of filling up the product information so I do not have an **address_id** to feed to the **Product** model. How can I do this? One option is to first save the data in **Address** model and then use the generated id to feed in to the **Product** model. Is there any better way to do it?
Lets say I'm first saving the **Address** model and then the **Product** model, suppose if the **Address** model gets saved and **User** model somehow triggered some exception. How do I rollback the saved address?

Here's my Controller Code :

```
    class Api::V1::ProductsController < ApplicationController

    respond_to :json

    def create
        product = Product.new(params[:product])
        if product.save
            render json: {success: "success"}, status: 200
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are facing a common issue mate. It is called nested models. You can address this issue with nested forms. There is a really nice video in the [RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/) talking about that. take a look [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1?autoplay=true). Try that out and let us know.

Comment: I did changed my controller and model code according to link, but when I'm trying to create the Product I'm getting the following error : 
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 25ms (ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)

ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError (ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError):
  app/controllers/api/v1/products_controller.rb:6:in `create'

Comment: That is probably your object_params method. Some params that are not in the model are coming through when you try to create the model

Comment: You can not use *params[:product]* inside the Product.new method because Rails will not allow to create a object without sanitize the params first.